# Getting data from an html page using R

Tags: html, r

Anyone can help me why the below code doe not have any data for the selected table?

```
library('httr')
library('rvest')
url= read_html("http://projects.worldbank.org/search?lang=en&searchTerm=&sectorcode_exact=AB")
table = html_node(url,"table#f05v5-sorting-table.border-top2.border-allside.clearboth")
```

Thanks!

Comment: I can't find the table from which you want to get the data

Comment: The tag#class.id that is being shown in the html_node is for the main table in that url.

Comment: I cannot find it. If you attach a screenshot showing the table you are interested in, I can help you further

Comment: the world bank has an API which is the way you're supposed to access the data. given the lack of a URL on previous question(s) please provide the real resource you're attempting to "legitimately scrape data from"

Comment: @prosoitos I'd avoid further aid. the OP has one other open q and refuses to share the actual URL so you may be setting yourself up for fines & penalties if the real one ever does come out.

Comment: This is the other URL (http://www.fao.org/gender-landrights-database/data-map/statistics/en/), I'm trying to get data of a table inside it.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Oh, I didn't even think about that side of things. Thanks for bringing my awareness on the question of legality when it comes to web scraping. I have helped workshops on it but I never use it myself, so this did not even cross my mind :\ Good to keep in mind though. Thank you.

Comment: Now that I see which table we are talking about (thanks to the comment below my answer), I can see that it is available for download as an .xls file). So I imagine that getting it in R directly is fine too.

Comment: @prosoitos Thanks for replying my comment. Do you know what might be wrong that I cannot get data for that table in R?

Comment: I think it is because it is not a "real" table. I am no html expert, so this is likely to be a clumsy answer. But the xpath does not have a `/div/table` part. I tried to run my suggested code and indeed it did not work. I also tried with `html_text()` instead of `html_table()` with no result either. So I think that is due to how the website is built.

Comment: But you can download that data as an .xls file. So why don't you do that and then import the file into R?

Comment: @prosoitos Thank you very much for your response. I'm still a beginner in R and as an assignment for a class I need to scrape data of a website.

Comment: It seems that you picked a wrong one for that. If you are free to choose any site, you can use this site which is built especially to learn webscraping (that is the website which was used in a workshop I helped for on the subject): http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books_1/index.html

Comment: As an added bonus, with this site, you don't have to worry about any legal aspect as it is all fake data made to play with.

Comment: @prosoitos I really appreciate your help. Yeah, it seems I haven't picked right websites. Thanks for suggesting that webpage.

Comment: Try to follow the workflow I suggested. You should be fine with those information. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some steps. Your workflow should look like this:

```
dat_html <- read_html(
  "http://projects.worldbank.org/search?lang=en&searchTerm=&sectorcode_exact=AB"
)

dat_nodes <- html_nodes(dat_html, xpath = "xxxx")

dat <- html_table(dat_nodes)
```

`dat` will be a list, so if you want a data frame, you could do something like:

```
dat_df <- as.data.frame(dat)
```

Or, if you like tibbles:

```
dat_tbl <- as_tibble(dat)
```

I cannot find the table you are interested in on that webpage, so you have to replace `"xxxx"` by the xpath of the table you are interested in.

To find the xpath, if you are inspecting the page from chrome or chromium, you can right click on the node in the inspector window, and look for `Copy`, then `Copy XPath`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, I am still getting no value in the dat_nodes variable. To see the table that I need its data, in that URL, you need to click on the "Projects" tap next to "Overview ". This is what I am running:
    dat_html <- read_html("http://projects.worldbank.org/search?lang=en&searchTerm=&sectorcode_exact=AB")

dat_nodes <- html_nodes(dat_html, xpath = '//*[@id="n07v1-generic-list-table"]')